# MySQL Select Multiple Row with column value

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table has columns tag_id and item_id,

```
---------------------
| tag_id  | item_id |
---------------------
|    1    |    2    |
|    2    |    2    |
|    4    |    2    |
|    3    |    5    |
|    5    |    7    |
|    11   |    5    |
---------------------
```

For example, I want to return item_id = 2 if I input tag_id = 1,2,4

what is the query should look like?

I am using Codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from table where tag_id in (1,2,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for Msql query that returns only one cell value you can use the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT item_id FROM tableName WHERE tag_id IN (1, 2, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.Will help you

```
  $this->db->select('item_id'); 
    $this->db->from('tblNAME');   
    $where = "tag_id='1'  OR tag_id='2' OR tag_id='2 ";
    $this->db->where($where);
    return $this->db->get()->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all answers but unfortunately not suitable for the use. Because I want it return exactly the item id = 2 if tag id = 1,2,4.

If we using IN(1,2,4) it will return item ids that has tag id 1 or 2 or 4.

Finally I figure out the SQL query should be

```
Select *, COUNT(item_id) AS id_count 
FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE tag_id IN(1,2,4) 
GROUP BY item_id HAVING id_count = 3
```

Therefore, express it in a general form, we simply replace the 3 by the size of the array of tag id.